# How to display table data at admin side in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, admin, drupal-webform

I have created custom table and entries in that table are done from frontend side using webform.

That whole process working fine also mail is sent to admin,BUT I need to display that table information to admin in separate page like in grid view or table listing

So Is there any way to do make a page and only admin can see that?

Comment: Do you need to do this in code or using UI options?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be able to use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) and the [Webform MySQL Views](https://drupal.org/project/webform_mysql_views) to achieve this. Basically, Views is a great module used to build and display data in Drupal (usually content). Webform data is not normally accessible in Views, but Webform MySQL Views fixes that.

Comment: I have installed and tried but it displays whole form posted data, but i need to display table data